# Plot 4D graph in python2.7

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot red, blue and green colors on the three axis and an array which stores the value corresoding to each combination of color in python2.7....when i run my program either becomes unresponsive for 24 hours or it gives me memory error. Here is my code:

```
import pylab
import math
from itertools import product
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N=[]
p=np.zeros((256,256,256))
S=[]
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')
X=np.arange(0,256,1) #for one of the features either red, blue or green
Y=np.arange(0,256,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
R=np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z=R/np.sqrt(2)
N=p.flatten();
N=(p[i,j,k] for k in Z)            
surf=ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                    facecolors=cm.jet(N),
                    linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
plt.show()
```

Please help. I have read the previous posts, and have used them, still I am getting memory error. Here p is a containing values of combinations of red, green and blue. For simplicity I have initialized it to zero...it is giving the following error..colset.append(fcolors[rs][cs])
IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/try2.py", line 22, in <module>
    N.append(prob_Skin[i,j,k])
MemoryError ---is the error message

Comment: At what part of the program do you get a memory error? Is it while you're appending to N? If so is it possible to pass cm.jet() a Generator instead of the entire list N. E.g. take the line N.append(P[i,j,k]), and instead, on the next line have N=(p[i,j,k] for i in X for j in Y for K in Z)

Comment: facecolors=cm.jet(N),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 565, in __call__
    lut.take(xa, axis=0, mode='clip', out=rgba)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array --This is the error that I am getting now. I am new to python and matplotlib, therefore I am not able to comprehend much.

Comment: I have made changes according to Matt's suggestions, still it is giving me error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your program is slow because you're doing a lot of unnecessary work building `N`.  You're building a 70 MB list a few bytes at a time (256*256*256=16,777,216 appends!).  A better (faster, memory efficient) way to build `p` is to use numpy's array broadcasting, and then reuse `p` to make `N`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(256)
p = a[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * a[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis] * a[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:] 
N = p.flatten()
```

Second and more importantly, you're not using plot_surface() correctly.  According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), X, Y and Z should be 2D arrays.  X and Y lay down a 2D grid and Z provides the "height" for each point on that 2D grid.  If you want to manually set the facecolor, it should also be a 2D array.  You should look at the example in the docs for a working example.

EDIT:

I'm not sure what your plot is intended to look like, so lets walk through the [MPL demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.py).

Make the necessary imports and create an axis object (yours does this correctly):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

Next, make an X/Y grid and corresponding Z.  In your program, X, Y and Z are 1D.  They describe a line in 3D space, not a surface.

```
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)  # <-- returns a 2D grid from initial 1D arrays
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
```

Lets first plot the simplest thing possible.  No colors, default anti-aliasing, lines, etc.

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now add a colors.  Note that the color comes from the Z component.

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now manually control the colors ([MPL inspiration](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo3.py)).

```
colortuple = ('y', 'k')  # only use two colors: yellow and black
xlen, ylen = X.shape  # get length of 
colors = np.empty(X.shape, dtype=str)  # make a 2D array of strings
for i in range(xlen):
    for j in range(ylen):
        index = (i + j) % 2  # alternating 0's and 1's
        colors[i,j] = colortuple[index]
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
        facecolors=colors)
```

[image]

If you want to color based on some other metric, you can create your own colormap.  There are many answered questions on how to do that.

Edit 2:

Colors can also be specified as RGB sequences.  For something like your red on X, green on Y description you could do this:

```
xlen, ylen = X.shape
colors = np.zeros((xlen,ylen,3))
jspan = np.linspace(0., 1., ylen)
ispan = np.linspace(0., 1., xlen)
for i in range(xlen):
    colors[i,:,0] = jspan
for j in range(ylen):
    colors[:,j,1] = ispan

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=colors,)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have made the changes in the question according to your suggestions. Still it is giving me error, please help

Comment: Can somebody please help...i have tried various forms, but still i am not getting the required answer